# What is the impact on cloned repositories after a git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm ...'

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have recently extracted a few subdirectories from a shared git repository with
`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all`

Now I have the subdirectories still left in the central shared repository and I would like to remove them. As far as I understood from searching the web something like
 `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD`
should be used to remove old Directories from the history.

While I believe this will work, I am now wondering if this is the best way to remove something from the history in the case where the repository is shared, as I understood that everyone with a local clone would basically have to re-clone the repository ?

So my ultimate question is, am I right with these assumptions or is there a way to remove Directories from multiple branches in the history without everyone having to clone the repository again?

**UPDATE**
So I ran some tests and an currently running with this command:
`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch -- Dir1 DIR2' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` which works but it also completely changes all SHA-1 keys of all commits, which is understandable but not desirable. And it would mean everybody has to re-clone the repository and all previous links via Gitweb are going to b broken.

Comment: We have now decided to just delete the files in the directories and commit those deletes it is not a security problem to have them in the rest of the history. But if anyone has a better idea please still answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot silently alter commits if other people already have them. That's how Git works and it is a feature.

Comment: I know that it is a feature, but I am wondering what the least disruptive way of achieving the goal is.

Comment: `git pull -f` is probably least disruptive. It will overwrite local history. But still you have to do it in each repository.